# Sitemap is showing Virtual folder name after the language code in Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7

Tags: sxa, sitemap

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with `SXA 1.7`. We have created one site where the `languages` used are `"zh-CN"` and `"en"` and configured the site to use virtual folder `"/cn"`. When we browse for sitemap it shows the `language code` after the `domain name` and after that, it shows the virtual folder directory.

[image]

I would like the `virtual folder` to come `first` and then the language code. Can anyone please suggest is this expected behavior in `SXA` if we use the Virtual folder concept? If not please suggest how to make it right?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009555/multi-regional-and-language-sites-sitecore it states that this is the default sitecore behavior of displaying the urls when virtual folder and language embedding are set.

Sitecore SXA uses a method `GetFullUrl` which renders the urls in the sitemap, if you take a look at the existing implementation of the `SitemapGenerator` service in `Sitecore.XA.Feature.SiteMetadata.dll`:

```
protected virtual string GetFullLink(Item item, SitemapLinkOptions options)
{
  string itemUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options.UrlOptions);
  return options.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + options.TargetHostname + itemUrl;
}
```

For the `rel="alternate"` links the GetFullUrl method is called with these options:

```
  UrlOptions urlOptions2 = (UrlOptions) urlOptions1.Clone();
  urlOptions2.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always;
```

If you want to customize your sitemap urls you can implement your own sitemap generator which will inherit from SXA `SitemapGenerator` service and override the GetFullUrl method.